# Recurrence Problem T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n

Tags: recurrence-relation

I am trying to get better at solving recurrence relations, so I am making my own simple relations and try to solve them. I have made the following recurrence:
$$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n$$

How can I solve $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + n$ using unfolding when $T(1) = 1$ ?

Comment: In addition to OmG's answer, keep in mind that unfolding is not a formal way to solve the recurrence. At some point in the unfolding you'll hand-wave by using dots and writing $T(n)$ as a function of $T(1)$. If you want a formal proof you'll need to use induction. (Or, in this case, you can just invoke the master theorem).

Comment: Adding a bit to @Steven, unfolding can be used to give you a guess for your induction proof. Most of the time this guess will be correct and the induction proof should flow easily with the result from unfolding.

Answer (score 1):

Using master theorem you can say it is $\Theta(n\log n)$. Also, try to expand the relation:
$$T(n) = 3(3T(\frac{n}{3^2}) + \frac{n}{3}) + n = 3^2 T(\frac{n}{3^2}) + 2n$$
If you continue the above expansion, you will get that $T(n) \sim n\log_3(n) = \Theta(n\log(n))$.